# Flutter - How to align selected item from DropdownButton?

Tags: drop-down-menu, flutter, alignment

I am unable to align the selected item from DropdownButton to the center.

I have tried child: Center() under the DropdownMenuItem, it is able to align those items however after I have selected one of the items, the selected item was aligned to the Left immediately. I would also like to align **the selected item** to the Center.

Anyone knows how to achieve it?

Thanks in advance.

[Unable to align selected item to Center](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lgyDu.png)

_dropdownValues:

```
final List<String> _dropdownValues = [
  "One",
  "Two12345",
  "Three123456789",
  "Four",
  ];

  String _selectedValue;
```

Under Widget Build:

```
body: Center(

        child: Row(

          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,

          children: <Widget>[
            Container( 
              child: Text('Name:',),
            ),

            Container(

              child: Center(
                child: DropdownButton(
                  hint: Text('Select ...'),
                  items: _dropdownValues.map((value) => DropdownMenuItem(
                    child: Center( child: Text(value), ),
                    value: value,
                  )).toList(),

                  onChanged: (String value) {
                    setState(() {
                      this._selectedValue = value;
                    });
                  },
                  isExpanded: false,
                  value: _selectedValue,
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

If you don't mind setting a fixed width you can wrap your `DropdownMenuItem` `Text` child in a `SizedBox`. Then you set the `textAlign` property to `TextAlign.center`, like so:

```
DropdownButton(
  // ...
  items: _dropdownValues.map((value) => DropdownMenuItem(
    child: SizedBox(
      width: 100.0, // for example
      child: Text(value, textAlign: TextAlign.center),
    ),
    value: value,
  )).toList(),
  // ...
),
```

Answer (score 20):

Incase someone stumble upon this issue. You need to specify width and this can be achieved by using `selectedItemBuilder` property of `DropdownButton`.

```
final List<String> items = <String>['1','2','3'];
String selectedItem = '1';

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Padding(
    padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 12.0),
    child: DropdownButton<String>(
      value: selectedItem,
      hint: Container(
        alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
        width: 180,
        child: Text("Hint text", textAlign: TextAlign.end)
      ),
      onChanged: (String string) => setState(() => selectedItem = string),
      selectedItemBuilder: (BuildContext context) {
        return items.map<Widget>((String item) {
          return Container(
            alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
            width: 180,
            child: Text(item, textAlign: TextAlign.end)
          );
        }).toList();
      },
      items: items.map((String item) {
        return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
          child: Text('Log $item'),
          value: item,
        );
      }).toList(),
    ),
  );
}
```

code from [here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/DropdownButton/selectedItemBuilder.html)

Comment: This should be the correct answer - the accepted one does not align the selected item, only the list. This answer does the job. Thanks!

Answer (score 9):

just add **Center** as parent  to child of DropdownMenuItem

```
   DropdownButton(
      items: genderList
          .map((string) => DropdownMenuItem(
                child: Center(
                  child: Text(
                    string,
                    style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.bodyText2,
                  ),
                ),
              ))
          .toList(), 
      
      onChanged: (value) {  },
    )
```

Answer (score 4):

You probably won't need this now but if anyone is wondering how I found the following solution.

```
DropdownButton(
   hint: Align(alignment: Alignment.centerRight, child: Text('any text')), 
   ...
   items: _dropdownValues.map((item) {
   return DropdownMenuItem(
            child: new Align(alignment: Alignment.centerRight, child: Text(item)),
            value: item,);
   }).toList(),
)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the expected behavior, default alignment of the menu item is centerLeft as per this link: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/3759

You can raise a new issue for this functionality on the flutter Github page.

Comment: That was 3 years ago and opposite behaviour. It mentioned that the text was center when selected and aligned left when dropdown. My code had already align center when dropdown but unable to align center when selected.

Answer (score 0):

```
DropdownButton(

alignment: Alignment.centerRight,

)
```